# HSQL and MSSQL datepart parameter

Tags: sql-server, database, hsqldb

I have an embedded HSQLDB database for testing. The production database is SQL Server 2012.

I am using a native query which has this predicate on the where:

```
and (pc.SOME_DATE IS NOT NULL 
AND pc.SOME_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATETIME() AND DATEADD(minute, c.MINUTES_TO_ADD, SYSDATETIME()))
```

and in SQLServer it runs ok, but on HSQLDB it fails with:

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: MINUTE
```

I solved the similar problem with the SYSDATETIME by creating a function, but I don't know how I can solve this incompatibility between mssql using a keyword and hsqldb using a varchar.

Any ideas on what I can do to my hsqldb to make this work? Or even to the query...

EDIT:
I know how to make the query work in HSQLDB, the point is to have the same query in SQLServer and in HSQLDB. Can I define some global variable named minute that would represent the value 'minute'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
DATEADD('minute', c.MINUTES_TO_ADD, SYSDATETIME())
```

There are also other functions for the same task:

```
TIMESTAMPADD ( SQL_TSI_MINUTE, c.MINUTES_TO_ADD, SYSDATETIME() )
```

SQLServer compatibility is likely to be improved in the next version of HSQLDB to support the query without any change.

**Updated:** Support for unquoted tokens for DATEADD and DATEDIFF functions has been added and committed to SVN /base/trunk. The jar can be compiled easily with Gradle or Ant after a checkout of this SVN directory.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know I can use 'minute', maybe I was not clear on that point. I want to know if I could define some global variable minute that would be 'minute' in HSQLDB. Btw in terms of compatibility in this case, according to w3schools, this is not a MSSQL compaitibilty, but a standard sql compatibility issue.

Comment: Session variables can be defined and accessed as input/output of procedures, but they cannot be accessed from individual queries.

Comment: timestampadd function does not exist in mssql or at least that was the result I got. So I guess that my question does not have an answer yet. Or the answer is: not possible.

Comment: I found the commit on sourceforge this seems like it is gonna be released on 3.2.5 version. To mark this as the correct answer in my opinion it should be stated that before 3.2.5 this is not possible.

Comment: I don't mind, but you asked "Any ideas on what I can do to my hsqldb to make this work" and the answer is to compile from SVN.